# WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT no longer disables home key on Android 4.1

Tags: android

On android Jelly Bean setting the alert dialog window type to WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT no longer disables home key. On ICS settings window type to WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT would block all key press. Is there any other way to avoid home key and recent app key from dismissing alert dialog on android JB??

I need to dismiss the alert dialog only by pressing OK on dialog. Please let me know how to stop home key and recent app key from dismissing the alert dialog

Comment: "Is there any other way to avoid home key and recent app key from dismissing alert dialog on android JB?" -- hopefully not.